# NHibernate Bulk Insert Without Selecting ID at the end

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been playing around with a few ways to batch insert a list of 10,000 objects into my database.

These objects don't have any relationships, and only store POCO data.

I have started using a StatelessSession as many articles have suggested and I have noticed a marked improvement.

One thing remains though - after each insert NHibernate does a SELECT statement to get the ID of the object it just inserted. Is there a way to defer this until when I am going to actually Query for the objects? It seems it would be a huge performance benefit if NHibernate could just insert the rows and not worry about the IDs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible, sometimes it is worth considering the right tool for the job. If you have an identity column on your table then NHibernate `ALWAYS` follows a select with an insert even for `BULK` inserts. Another thing to consider is that your level one cache is going to grow quite large (unless you use stateless sessions) and this could lead to other complications.

I understand your point of view wanted to use the goodness of NHibernate but sometimes we just can't avoid using other tools...

If I need to send 10K inserts into my database I for one would use the `SQlBulkCopy` class and bypass NHibernate altogether.

> SQLBulkCopy lets you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with
>   data from another source.

See [here for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) info

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Unfortunately, one of my goals is to remain DB agnostic. Because of this - I will probably live with the 10-15 seconds it takes to insert 10k rows with NHibernate.

Comment: Personally, I still would use the `SQLBulkCopy` for SQL Server as this will make your application more zippier and will not tie up resources for other users/usage. I wish you good luck with your goals!

Comment: While the ideal of being database agnostic is good, in practice it can be difficult to achieve

Comment: Isn't the ID not generated from DB (e.g. HiLo) going to skip the read from DB again?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ID generation to use guids or some other server side calculated type and thus sql does not need to return the ids as you already know them and just pass them in the sql query for the insert

see [this](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) for more details of the available approaches

and [this](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx) for a bit more indepth explaination into the generators

Comment: Thanks. I understand the different types of generators, but don't want to use them to solve this problem. It should be possible to tell NHibernate it can throw the object away and not keep it in the cache (at which point it would have no need to select the ID)

Comment: doing an large import like you are it might be worthwhile dropping down to the sql level and issuing the sql directly if your model is simple enough, otherwise you might be able to achieve something using HQL perhaps. Generally speaking I think changing generators is your best chance of success as thats what their designed to do, I don't think you can make nhibernate "forget" about an object like you want

Comment: is there a particular reason you don't want to use the different generators?

Comment: I am also not willing to drop it down to the SQL level for a query this simple. That would be a lot of manual work and magic strings for such a simple task. And I do not want to use an ID other than an autoIncrementing integer because it is more than sufficient for my current needs.